# Italian sausage

Tags: raw-meat

I accidentally didn't refrigerate a package of ground Italian sausage when I returned from the grocery.  It sat out at room temp for almost 3 hours.  How safe should I assume it is?

Comment: Don't forget to use the search bar to see if your question already has an answer.